# How to display hypertexted link with alternative display title?

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms

So I'm working with google forms and I have a paragraph block where I want a click-able link to be displayed with a condensed title, so in other words instead of having this entire  displayed hyperlink be:

https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/892aa419-9de8-47c5-9103-9cdba4590e96/downloads/ReviewerGuideAmazonArmy.pdf?ver=1559470668146

I want the link to just show display text like "View PDF" then when you click that display text it will bring you to the actual link.

Not sure what is required to do this or if it's possible within google forms, but I'd appreciate any help

```
var textItem = form.addTextItem().setTitle('https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/892aa419-9de8-47c5-9103-9cdba4590e96/downloads/ReviewerGuideAmazonArmy.pdf?ver=1559470668146');
```